# proving level of median in heap

Tags: algorithm, median, binary-heap

I need to prove that the median of binary heap (doesn't matter if it is a min heap or max heap) can be in the lowest level of the heap (in the leaf). I am not sure how to prove it. I thought about using the fact that a heap is a complete binary tree but I am not sure about it. How can I prove it?

Comment: What do you mean by "can be"? "There is a heap such that..." or "elements of any heap can be rearranged such that..."?

Comment: I mean there is a heap such that...

Comment: Take a heap where all elements are the same.

Comment: Is there another way to provr it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Evg mentioned in the comments, if all elements are the same, this is trivially true. Assume that all elements need to be different, and let us focus on the case with an odd amount of nodes 2H+1 and a min heap (the max heap case is similar).  To create the min heap where the median is at the bottom, first insert the smallest H elements.

There are two cases. Case 1; after doing this the binary tree formed by these H elements is completely filled (every layer is filled) then you can just insert the remaining H+1 elements on the last layer  (which you can do since the maximum capacity of the last layer equals (#total_nodes+1)/2 which is precisely H+1).

Case 2 The last layer still has some unfilled spaces. In this case, take the smallest remaining nodes from the largest H elements until this layer is filled (note that there will be no upward movement in your heap since these elements are already larger than whatever is in the tree). Then start the next layer by inserting the median. Finally insert the remaining nodes, which won't be moved upwards either since they are larger than whatever is in the layer above, by construction. By the same argument about the capacity of the last layer, you will not need to start a new layer during this process.

In the case where there are an even amount of nodes 2H, you can argue similarly, but you would have to define the median as H+1 smallest node (otherwise the statement you want to prove is false, as you can see by noticing that the only possible min-heap for the set {1,2} is the tree with root at 1 and leaf at 2).

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to prove it is just to make one:

```
                    1
             2             3
          4     5       6     7
```

Any complete heap with nodes in level order will have the median at the left-most leaf, but you don't have to prove *that*.